# How to find the Azure image size?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

In Azure, i have created an image from a VM as below.
[image]
I want to check the image size but i cannot find it from the portal. Also i have checked [Az Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azimage?view=azps-4.3.0) and az cli, but i didn't see any commands giving me its size. Is there a way to get this info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$resourceId = "" # The resource ID of your image
$i=Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId $resourceId
$diskSize = $i.Properties.storageProfile.osDisk.diskSizeGB
```